# create-react-app eintegrity error windows

Tags: reactjs, npm

I got these error when i started creating react app in my windows 10 pc. Please help me to fix this.

```
PS F:\> npm install -g create-react-app
C:\Users\Harshit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\Harshit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\ind
ex.js
+ create-react-app@1.4.0
updated 1 package in 24.169s
PS F:\> create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in F:\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-IeCr+vbyApzy+vsTNWenAdQTVSQ= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-IeCr+vbyApzy+vsTNWenAdQTVSQ= but got sha1
-reRBygSiSrbV6gYVeXXD3kFgUvo=. (5518 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Harshit Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-10T06_11_12_677Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app / from F:\
Done.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try: `npm cache verify`

Or update npm : `npm i -g npm`

Answer (score 1):

Check [this github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16861) for a possible solution.

> Deleting npm and npm-cache folders in Users%username%\AppData\Roaming
>   (windows 7) and running npm install fixed it for me