# Can anybody tell me about why this error is coming in my pc when creating a react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

[This is the error coming in windows 11 please anybody know the solution please tell me the solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHocG.png)

Comment: Is your internet fine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137992/create-react-app-eintegrity-error-windows does it solve your problem?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58389506/npm-err-code-eintegrity-when-i-run-create-react-app

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow :)! Please read the following guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Especially the section not posting pictures of code/errors. Other than that I think the links provided in the comments are worth a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your internet connection (or maybe in your proxy)